# PKRevealController with TabBarController as initial view

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I've set up a PKRevealController menu for my app, and it works great. However I want to put the menu on a view located inside of a Tab Bar Controller. Right now it only works on views not embedded inside of a Tab Bar Controller. Does anyone know how I can make that happen?

See existing code below.

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.revealController = (PKRevealController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UIViewController *leftViewController = [[LeftMenuViewController alloc] init];
    PKRevealController *frontViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainNavViewController"];
    [self.revealController setFrontViewController:frontViewController];
    [self.revealController setLeftViewController:leftViewController];
    return YES;
}
```